# How to use python to create a table of data from a csvFileObject?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a table using data from a csv file in a browser website, but I just can't seem to get it. Basically, I am trying to have a python program and a csv file in the same folder, and people who browse to my website will be able to see the data from the csv file displayed as a table, as it would be in a program like excel. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'content-type: text/html\n'
import csv
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

reader = csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'))
print '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <h1> Diabetes Across Different Groups</h1>
    </head>
    <body>  <table border='1'>
    <th>Demographic</th>
    <th>Data Years</th>
    <th>Estimated Number of Diabetics</th>
    <th>Percent of Adults in that Demographic</th>
    <th>Standard Error for Percent</th>'''
rownum = 0
    for row in reader: # reads rows from the CSV file
        if rownum == 0:
            print '<tr>'
            for column in row: #reads a column from row
                print '<td>' + column + '</td>'
            print '</tr>'

  #write all other rows
    else:

      rownum += 1 #increment row



print ''' </table>
        <p> </p>
    </body>
</html>'''
```

Comment: `Pandas` has a `to_html()` function. So you would do something like `import pandas as pd`, then load the csv file `df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")` and if things are correctly formatted then `html_table = df.to_html()` should give you a HTML version of the CSV file. You can then append/insert the HTML output to your website

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your code as follows:

```
import csv
import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

print 'content-type: text/html\n'

print '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Diabetes Across Different Groups</title>
</head>

<body>  
<h1>Diabetes Across Different Groups</h1>
<table border='1'>
    <th>Demographic</th>
    <th>Data Years</th>
    <th>Estimated Number of Diabetics</th>
    <th>Percent of Adults in that Demographic</th>
    <th>Standard Error for Percent</th>'''

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    #header = next(csv_input)       # optionally skip header in CSV file

    for row in csv_input:  # reads a row at a time from the CSV file
        print '    <tr><td>{}</td></tr>'.format('</td><td>'.join(row))

print '''</table>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>'''
```